# Handle interaction between HTML and Swift using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, progressive-web-apps

WKWebView not able to trigger javascript in the loaded Web Page.

Scenario:
If user click image in Website, it should get update.

Using javascript to update the image on the website, if the user clicks a image.

1. included .js file in project
2. configured WKWebview
3. Enabled JavaScript
4. Added Script in WKWebview

**Function in JS file like :**

```
function captureImage(bucket,fileName){
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.captureImage.postMessage("showCamera")
}
```

**Accessing this function in Swift like:**

```
      webViewPWA.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "captureImage")


///This function handles the event generated by javascript
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
         print("Webview Message received: \(message.name) with body: \(message.body)")
        if (message.name == "captureImage"){
            print("\(message.body)")

            let body = message.body
            if let action:String = body as? String {
                switch action {
                case "showCamera":
                    print("camera image triggering, capture image for JS")
                    //take necessary action
                    break
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        return
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you click on image is print("camera image triggering, capture image for JS") getting executed?

Comment: yes it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Once the picture is captured on the device in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method like:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    }
```

You can run any JS you want in a WKWebView by using `evaluateJavaScript()` and get a result in Swift.

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('someElement').innerText") { (response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
          print("evaluateJavaScript error -- \(String(describing: error))")
          return
        }
        print("evaluateJavaScript response -- \(String(describing: response))")
}
```

it would also be nice to have something similar to WebBridge.js that provides functions for communicating with the build ing WKWebView in iOS and he android webview

and inside of the WebBridge.js you can define:

```
/* install global handler for WebView to call methods */
    if (!window.WebBridge) {
      window.WebBridge = (function () {
        var actions = []


        return {
          receive: function (actionName, json) {
            if (typeof actions[actionName] !== 'undefined') {
              actions[actionName](json)
            }
          },
          registerActionHandler: function (actionName, method) {
            actions[actionName] = method
          }
        }
      })()
    }
```

then from Swift file you can narrow down the structure of your JS calls:

```
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("WebBridge.receive('yourCustomActionName', '{\"yourRey\": \"yourValue\"}')") { (response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
          print("evaluateJavaScript error -- \(String(describing: error))")
          return
        }
        print("evaluateJavaScript response -- \(String(describing: response))")
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Nick this is helpful for me